# Ansible - Check if a resource group exists in Azure

Tags: ansible

I am trying to implement some logic in ansible to check if a resource group exists or not in azure. If it exists it should fail/abort the execution, if not it should continue.

If have created this:

```
---

- name: Login to Azure
  shell: az login --service-principal -u username -p password --tenant tenant

- name: Check if Resource Group exists
  shell: az group exists -n azure_resource_group_name
  register: rg_info

- name: FAIL If Resource Group exists
  fail:
    msg: "The Resource Group exists!!!"
  when: (rg_info.stdout == 'true')
```

Is there other way to do this using ansible native or azure modules, instead of shell? Thanks.

Comment: You can write the `when` clause as: when: `rg_info.stdout`.

Comment: ok thanks. But any way to do the some thing using azure modules for ansible? Not shell

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect answer, but what you basically want is:

1. Install the Azure collection for Ansible, `ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection`.
2. Ensure to install [all requirements](https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/blob/dev/requirements-azure.txt) via python as well.

Once that is done, you should be able to use the modules.

3. Login [via az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

Once you're authenticated, you can check for the resource group:

```yaml
- name: query all the resources in the resource group
  azure_rm_resource_info:
    resource_group: whatever
    resource_type: resources
  register: az_resource

- debug:
    msg: "{{ az_resource }}"
```

Based on that output, you can create the resource group only if it not exists:

```yaml
- name: create a resource group
  azure_rm_resourcegroup:
    name: whatever
    location: westus
    tags:
        testing: stackoverflow
        delete: never
  when: not az_resource.<depends on output of previous task>
```

Comment: The login via az cli looks alike the one i have using shell: az login --service-principal -u username -p password --tenant tenant. Is there a way to login with ansible whithout shell using ansible?

Comment: It's not supported by the modules. So, so far, no. Either write your own plugin, or do it via shell.

Comment: So in order to check if a resource group exists or not I have to use a az login first and than use azure_rm_resourcegroup? No way to do this only with ansible or any azure module?

Comment: The way I read it, the resource group is not idempotent. It's either create or delete. You can try it out yourself.

Comment: ok. Thanks for your help